# DNS seeder 'options'

Tags: dns

I've seen various 'options' that the different DNS seeders support, for example x1, x5, x9, and xd:

```
vSeeds.emplace_back("seed.bitcoin.sipa.be", true); // Pieter Wuille, only supports x1, x5, x9, and xd
vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.bluematt.me", true); // Matt Corallo, only supports x9
vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org", false); // Luke Dashjr
vSeeds.emplace_back("seed.bitcoinstats.com", true); // Christian Decker, supports x1 - xf
vSeeds.emplace_back("seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch", true); // Jonas Schnelli, only supports x1, x5, x9, and xd
vSeeds.emplace_back("seed.btc.petertodd.org", true); // Peter Todd, only supports x1, x5, x9, and xd
```

(from [chainparams.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp))

But I can't find anything which actually explains what these options are. What do these options do and why do only some seeders offer some of the options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is 'service bit filtering.'

You can run `nslookup seed.bitcoin.sipa.be`, and get a list of bitcoin nodes.

You can also run `nslookup x1.seed.bitcoin.sipa.be`, and get a list of nodes with NODE_NETWORK set.

([source 1](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1888573.msg18791989#msg18791989). [source 2](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/9d31ed2e69fd5cde5fbc5208bd04276a58afd132/src/net.cpp#L1578).)

Comment: So the number following the X is like a bitmask for the service bits? Makes sense, thanks :)

Comment: Exactly, it sets what bits are required in the result.